# How to make the sizes of two images match in Idrisi ?

Tags: resize, image-resizing

So, I have this usual error message where the number of rows and columns of my images don't match (in cross ref).
I have generalised one of my images and then use expand to make the resolutions match again.
However, in the process I lost a few columns (which doesn't bother me), however, I don't know what to do in order to make my both images the same size again. 
Can someone help me ?

Thank you very much 
L.

Answer (score 0):

To make similar column and rows,

1. Convert layer from raster to vector (rastervector conversion tool)
2. Convert the vector converted layer in to raster (resample the layer that has required column and row)